# Presentation error for online judge in C++

Tags: c++, presentation

This is the problem. https://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/838/. Essentially its to create a square with layers that keep increasing like so.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have already figured out the logic and have implemented it myself. I can replicate the testcase and tried to work out some examples.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int f(int n)
{
    return -1 + 2 * n;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
        {
            cout << k << ' ';
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; j++)
            {
                cout << i << ' ';
            }
        }
        else if (i > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - f(i); j++)
            {
                cout << i << ' ';
            }
        }
        for (int k = i - 1; k > 0; k--)
        {
            if (k == i - 1) {
                cout << i << ' ';
            } else {
                cout << ' ' << i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int w = n - 1; w > 0; w--)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < w; k++)
        {
            cout << k << ' ';
        }
        if (w == 1)
        {
            for (int s = 2 * n - 1; s > 0; s--)
            {
                cout << w << ' ';
            }
        }
        else if (w > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - f(w); j++)
            {
                cout << w << ' ';
            }
        }
        for (int k = w - 1; k > 0; k--)
        {
            if (k == w - 1) {
                cout << w << ' ';
            } else {
                cout << ' ' << w;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

However it is always giving me a so called presentation error whilst I can match the sample case. Hence I am not sure how to fix my answer.

Comment: Are you supposed to have a space at the end of each line? Probably not, so you'll have to figure out a way around that. Perhaps print the space before each value except the first on each line.

Comment: Oh thats a good idea i'll give it a shot thanks

Comment: I hope you're aware of [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Yeah I am aware, just decided to use it for strictly competitions. In project work I take note of that. Thanks for the heads up still.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simpler way to go about this

```
void printSq(const int N) {
   for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r)
      for (int c = 0; c < N; ++c) {
         std::cout << std::min({r+1, c+1, N-r, N-c}) << " \n"[c == N-1];
      }
}
```

Comment: It prints a space after every column and \n after the last one. The string is indexed by a bool (0|1).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm horrified or amazed by that trick! :)